# smart lockscreen doesn't work on mobile touch (javascript and jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm trying to replicate a simple smart lockscreen, similar to those you see in android, but for a webapp.
This would be only a "fake login" so I don't mind for the security problems.

My problem here is that the lockscreen works perfectly with my mouse, and it doesn't work with touchscreens.

I've saw that, to make it work both with `mouse` and `touch`, I can use something like `$(canvasid).bind('mousemove touchmove',function(e)` but still only works with mouse.

here's my code

```js
    var dots=9;
    var trues=new Array(dots);
    var rects=new Array(dots);
    var lines=[];
    var pattern=new Array(dots);
    var cpattern=new Array(dots);
    var ink="rgb(3,42,57, 0.2)";
    var success="#fefefe";
    var spaint="#000";
    var end,start,index=1,stroke=2;
    var startx,starty,endx,endy,enddx,enddy,width,height;
    var c,ctx,radius=8,ind;
    var timer,interval;
    var patternSet=false,settingPattern=false,patternCorrect=false,drawing=false;
    //////// Assign The Components Here //////////////
    var canvasid="#mycanvas";
    var changeBtnId="#change";
    var outputId="#pattern";

$(document).ready(function(){
    c=document.getElementById(canvasid.substr(1));
////////////////////////Assigning Event Listeners/////////////////////////////////////////
    $(changeBtnId).on('click',function(){
        settingPattern=true;
    });
    $(canvasid).bind('mousedown touchstart',function(e){
        if(timer){
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        resetScreen();
        startx=e.offsetX;
        starty=e.offsetY;
        index=1;
        for(i=0;i<dots;++i){
            if(rects[i].contains(new Point(startx,starty))){
                startx=rects[i].getCenterX();
                starty=rects[i].getCenterY();
                endx=startx;
                endy=starty;
                trues[i]=true;
                pattern[i]=index;
                start=i;
                drawing=true;
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    $(canvasid).bind('mouseup touchend',function(e){
        drawing=false;
        printPattern();
        if(settingPattern==true){
            for(i=0;i<dots;++i){
                cpattern[i]=pattern[i];
            }
        }else{
            if(patternCheck()==true){
                patternCorrect=true;
            }
        }
        timer=setTimeout(function(){
            if(patternCorrect==true){
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            settingPattern=false;
            patternCorrect=false;
            resetScreen();
        },1500);
    });
    $(canvasid).bind('mousemove touchmove',function(e){
        if(drawing==true){
            endx=e.offsetX;
            endy=e.offsetY;
            for(i=0;i<rects.length;++i){
                if(trues[i]!=true){
                    if(rects[i].contains(new Point(endx,endy))){
                        index+=1;
                        enddx=rects[i].getCenterX();
                        enddy=rects[i].getCenterY();
                        lines.push(new Line(startx, starty, enddx, enddy));
                        startx=enddx;
                        starty=enddy;
                        end=i;
                        if((start==0&&end==2)||(start==2&&end==0)){
                            if(trues[1]==false){
                            trues[1]=true;pattern[1]=index;index+=1;}}
                        if((start==3&&end==5)||(start==5&&end==3)){
                            if(trues[4]==false){
                            trues[4]=true;pattern[4]=index;index+=1;}}
                        if((start==6&&end==8)||(start==8&&end==6)){
                            if(trues[7]==false){
                            trues[7]=true;pattern[7]=index;index+=1;}}
                        if((start==0&&end==6)||(start==6&&end==0)){
                            if(trues[3]==false){
                            trues[3]=true;pattern[3]=index;index+=1;}}
                        if((start==1&&end==7)||(start==7&&end==1)){
                            if(trues[4]==false){
                            trues[4]=true;pattern[4]=index;index+=1;}}
                        if((start==2&&end==8)||(start==8&&end==2)){
                            if(trues[5]==false){
                            trues[5]=true;pattern[5]=index;index+=1;}}
                        if((start==0&&end==8)||(start==8&&end==0)){
                            if(trues[4]==false){
                            trues[4]=true;pattern[4]=index;index+=1;}}
                        if((start==2&&end==6)||(start==6&&end==2)){
                            if(trues[4]==false){
                            trues[4]=true;pattern[4]=index;index+=1;}}
                            start=i;
                            trues[i]=true;
                            pattern[i]=index;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    });

    //////////////////// Setting Interval For Repainting The Screen ///////////////////////////
    interval=setInterval(paint,25/2);
});

/**
* The Paint Function Draws The Dots
*/

function paint(){
    ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    width=c.width;
    height=c.height;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    ctx.fillStyle="#000";
    ctx.lineWidth=radius*0.8;
    ctx.lineJoin="round";
    ctx.lineCap="round";
    ctx.strokeStyle=ink;
    ctx.shadowColor = "rgb(0, 0, 0)"; 
    //ctx.shadowBlur = radius/2;
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
    if(settingPattern==true){
        ctx.strokeStyle=spaint;
    }
    if(patternCorrect==true){
        ctx.strokeStyle=success;
    }
    for(i=0;i<lines.length;++i){
        lines[i].draw();
    }
    if(drawing==true){
        new Line(startx,starty,endx,endy).draw();
    }
    ind=0;
    for(i=width/6;i<width;i+=width/3){
        for(j=height/6;j<height;j+=height/3){
            fillCircle(i,j);
            if(trues[ind]==true){
                ctx.lineWidth=2;
                ctx.strokeStyle="red";
                strokeCircle(i,j);
            }
            rects[ind]=new Rectangle(i-radius,j-radius,radius*2,radius*2); 
            ind++;    
        }
    } 
}


/**
* This Function Resets The Pattern
*/

function resetScreen(){
    while(lines.length>0){
        lines.pop();
    }
    for(i=0;i<trues.length;++i){
        trues[i]=false;
        pattern[i]=0;
    }
    
}

/**
* Checks If The Pattern Is Correct Or Not
*@return Returns True If Pattern Is Correct Else False
*/

function patternCheck(){
    var correct=true;
    for(i=0;i<dots;++i){
        if(cpattern[i]!=pattern[i]){
            correct=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return correct;
    console.log(pattern);
}

/**
* Prints The Pattern On The Component
*/

function printPattern(){
    $(outputId).html("Pattern="+pattern);










///////////////////verifico codice pattern e redirect
///////////////////
///////////////////
///////////////////
///////////////////
    psw = [3,2,1,0,4,0,5,6,7];
    console.log(psw);
    console.log(pattern);

    if(JSON.stringify(pattern)==JSON.stringify(psw)) {
        console.log("correct password");
        window.location.href = 'website';
    }
    else{
        console.log("incorrect password");  
    }
}












//////////////// The Line Class ////////////////////////
function Line(startx,starty,endx,endy){
    this.startx=startx;
    this.starty=starty;
    this.endx=endx;
    this.endy=endy;
    this.draw=function(){
        ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(this.startx,this.starty);
            ctx.lineTo(this.endx,this.endy);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
    }
}

/**
* It Draws And Fills The Circle With Centres(i,j)
*/

function fillCircle(i,j){
        ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(i,j,radius,(Math.PI/180)*0,(Math.PI/180)*360,false);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
}

/**
* It Draws The Circle With Centres(i,j)
*/

function strokeCircle(i,j){
        ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(i,j,radius*3,(Math.PI/180)*0,(Math.PI/180)*360,false);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
}

/////////////// The Rectangle Class ////////////////////////////
function Rectangle(x,y,width,height){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.width=width;
    this.height=height;
    this.contains=function(point){
        if(point.x>=this.x&&point.x<=(this.x+this.width)&&point.y>=this.y&&point.y<=(this.y+this.height)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    this.getCenterX=function(){
        return this.x+this.width/2;
    }

    this.getCenterY=function(){
        return this.y+this.height/2;
    }
}

/////////////// The Point Class //////////////////////////
function Point(x,y){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}
```

```css
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
body {
  transition: 0s;
}
.canvas-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 720px;
  width: 720px;
}
#cnv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 800px) {
  .canvas-container {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.8);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.8);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .canvas-container {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.6);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.6);
  }
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="350" height="350" class="glowing-border">
Sorry Your Browser Doesn't Supports Canvas
</canvas>
```

Could somebody help me please?